# Горячие клавиши в Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm

В PyCharm есть возможность перейти в библиотеку по нажатии Ctrl и левая кнопка мыши, знаю что такое же должно быть в VScode, подскажите как настроить или где включается такая опция.

Comment: По идее должно быть достаточно расширения Python ([ms-python.python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)), и будет точно так же через Ctrl-клик переходить. Ну и для навигации по проекту нужно чтобы он был открыт как папка (меню File - Open folder).